# Rails model - returning 2 collections in 1 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, activerecord

Not thinking about this correctly so please help illuminate.  Have a model Students with genders male and female.

```
@students = Student.all
@females = Student.where(gender: "female")
@males = Student.where(gender: "male")
```

Can parse @students fine.  How can I return 1 hash with 'male' and 'female' as keys?

```
@coed = {male: @males, female: @females}
```

Iterating over this hash, nothing happens:

```
<% @coed.each do |gender, students| %>
<p>Hello</p>
<% end %>
```

returns a blank screen.

Comment: I would think what you are doing is correct, and am confused why you wouldn't be getting 2 `<p>Hellos<p>`

Even if @females and @males returned no results, iterating over that hash would still result in 2 "Hellos"

    a = { :foo => nil, :bar => nil }
    a.each do |_,_|
       puts "Hello"
    end
    >> "Hello"
    >> "Hello"

Answer (score 0):

The hash itself is fine.  I suspect your error is elsewhere.

You should see a return with 2 results, one for male one for female, even if nil.

```
{:male=>[#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Student id: 1, name: "z", gender: "male", 
  created_at: "2015-01-01 01:01:01", updated_at: "2015-01-01 01:01:01">], 
  female=>[#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Student id: 13, name: "a", gender: "female",
  created_at: "2015-01-01 01:01:01", updated_at: "2015-01-01 01:01:01">]}
```

If you've simplified your each loop for the sake of the SO question, that might explain the white screen.

In order to process your results you'll need an inner loop as well, since the male and female results will be in arrays.

So if you were displaying this info in a table, it might look something like:

```
<tbody>
  <% @coed.each do |gender, students| %>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2><h2><%= gender %></h2></td>
    </tr>
    <% students.each do |student| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= student.name %></td>
        <td><%= student.gender %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```